# Are dropped-out weights updated after second iteration?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

When training, if dropout is used, in the iteration, some weight are set to zero. Then loss is calculated and gradient is calculated for weight update. Weights are updated before the next iteration. Are the dropped weights also updated?

It makes sense to update them sinse otherwise the network would be dead after some iterations, but wanted to ask to be sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a specific iteration, the weights that are randomly dropped (set to zero) are NOT updated in that iteration. Note that these weights will be dropped ONLY for the current iteration.

In the next iteration, different weights will be dropped, again only for this specific iteration. Weights that were previously dropped and now are not, will have the values they had **before** the dropout.

This way, all of the network's weights will be trained.

TL;DR: Dropped weights are set to zero only for the current iteration, and then reclaim their previous values.